# Interpretation of mean in R while applying `group_by` function

Tags: r, mean

I am working through "R for Data Science by Grolemund and a question is asking me to assess some data. The data comes from the `nycflights13` data set. I'm just trying to understand the interpretation of the `mean()` function how I applied it.

```
delay_char = flights %>% 
              group_by() %>% 
              summarize(n = n(), 
                fifteen_early = mean(arr_delay == - 15, na.rm = T)
```

What I want to understand is what value was calculated as the mean? I believe what was output by the program was the proportion of flights out of the whole data set that have the criteria `arr_delay == -15`. But this is not the mean. Would I need to use another criteria on top of `arr_delay == -15` to get a mean that relates to that specific subset?

I think I may have partially answered my own question, but I still am curious as to what R did within my string of code.

Comment: If you want the mean for a group with a subset, you should filter down to the subset and then summarize by group. See the dplyr documentation https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/group_by

Comment: Taking the mean of a logical vector returns the proportion that are `TRUE`

Comment: Thank you guys for your explanations.